# MongoDB - unique index over entire Set

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to create a **unique** index in MonboDB over an **entire** Set lets say UserId's?

Example code

```
@Indexed
val participantIds: Set<UserId>
```

Such that, the **entire** Set is **unique**. This combination only exists **once**.

Example

```
[1, 2] // OK
[2, 3] // OK
[2, 1] // NOT OK (combination exists already)
```

**UPDATE**

The use case is for a messaging system. The *participantIds* are the members of that single or group messenger.

After reading the answers, I feel checking it in the e.g. *Service Layer* might be my use case with a *$all* / *$size* query check to verify that such combination does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a unique index for an array or collection attribute. You must check this constraint in the business logic.

Probably the best solution is adding a previous validation step before trying to persist your data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution that Mongodb provides.

You'll have to implement a workaround yourself, what I would do personally would be unique indexing a new field which would contain the set numbers:

```
const newDoc = { participantIds: [1, 2, 3]};
const uniqueStr = newDoc.participantIds.sort().join('');

await db.collection.insertOne({ ...newDoc, uniqueField: uniqueStr });
```

Now by building a unique index on `uniqueField` you could maintain this. Mind you this field will need to be updated on every document update which adds a lot of overhead.

Maybe if you could provide more details as to what you're trying to do and achieve it would be easier to help you come up with a more viable solution.

Comment: The set of _participantIds_ rarely updates, but it might be. It's for a messenger. 1:1 messaging and group messaging. The _participantIds_ are the members of the group. You gave some valuable input e.g. sorting and creating a hash. However, I think @Eduardo also made a valid point, checking it in the service layer.